# How to view email address details in mu4e?

Tags: mu4e

I started using `mu4e` for email and would like to see the details of email addresses of both sender and original recipient. My default view is

```
From: Some sender
```

and I would like to see their address, which I can do by replying to the email, when I see:

```
To: Some sender <name@email.com>
```

I would also like to see the email address of the original recipient in case of forwarding of multiple addresses, e.g. to know which address to fill in a form to unsubscribe.

I believe both of these are HTML headers, but the "headers" keyword means the email list view in `mu4e`.

How can I see these addresses?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set the following variable in your Emacs init file (or try it in the `*scratch*` buffer)

```
(setq mu4e-view-show-addresses 't)
```

In a pinch, you can also look at the raw message when in view mode with a period (`.`).